# Ability to enter a message on rollback

Tags: feature-request, edits, rollbacks

I would suggest to provide the ability to enter an optional edit message when performing a rollback. You could use the edit message to further explain the intent of the rollback.

[`$ git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) is a good example.

---

For instance, yesterday I rolled back a closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3856737/revisions) to a previous version in order to reinstate the "Possible Duplicate" message that was intentionally removed by an user (causing the question to become useless with no reference).

Because the user edited the question a few times, I wanted to explain the reason of the rollback and I was expecting to be able to enter a message.

Note. I searched for this [rollbacks](/questions/tagged/rollbacks) feature request, but I didn't find any result. I apologize in advance if it was already suggested in the past.

Answer (score 8):

Rollback is supposed to be a one-click way of quickly reverting an edit.

If you want to revert with a custom message, hit "edit" on the old revision, and save the edit with whatever message you want. This will effectively roll back to that old revision.

> [image]

Comment: Leaving the message as optional will not make the rollback less `one-click`.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Where in the revisions UI will you stuff text boxes for rollback text then? And again, you can already do exactly what you are asking for in the question using the edit link I mentioned in the answer.